# Displaying images from javascript array in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to use javascript to display html code (mix of text and images) in a div. The images are stored in an array, and which ones display will depend on a variable (handValue) put in to an if/else statement.

I think my syntax / concatenation is incorrect but can't quite figure it out.

The arrays that I have declared are as follows:

```
//Array for card images. 
       var startHand = ['images/cards/cardResult1',
                        'images/cards/cardResult2',
                        'images/cards/cardResult3',
                        'images/cards/cardResult4',
                        'images/cards/cardResult5',
                        'images/cards/cardResult6',
                        'images/cards/cardResult7',
                        'images/cards/cardResult8']
                                                ;

//Array for card tooltips. Each tooltip matches with a card category. 
       var toolTips = ['Category 1: AA, AKs, KK, QQ, JJ',
                       'Category 2: AK, AQs, AJs, KQs, TT',
                       'Category 3: AQ, ATs, KJs, QJs, JTs, 99',
                       'Category 4: AJ, KQ, KTs, QTs, J9s, T9s, 98s, 88',
                       'Category 5: A9s - A2s, KJ, QJ, JT, Q9s, T8s, 97s, 87s, 77, 76s',
                       'Category 6: AT, KT, QT, K9s, J8s, 86s, 75s, 65s, 66, 55, 54s',
                       'Category 7: K8s - K2s, Q8s, T7s, J9, T9, 98, 64s, 53s, 44, 43s, 33, 22',
                       'Category 8: A9, K9, Q9, J8, J7s, T8, 96s, 87, 85s, 76, 74s, 65, 54, 42s, 32s'];
```

My function is as follows. I assume a for loop would also tidy up my code (there are 8 categories in total). So any help on that would be appreciated too.

```
if (handValue >= 0.9) {
     return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "You can play any two cards from this position.";
                                }

     else {
            return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = 'You should play if your cards are in one of the following categories:<br><br><table>';


    //Category 1
            if (handValue < 0.06) {
             return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = 
                '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td>';
                                            }                  

    //Category 2
                 else if (handValue < 0.20) {
             return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = 
                '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[1] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[1] + '</span></td>';
                                            }

    //Category 3
                 else if (handValue < 0.40) {
               return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = 
          '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[1] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[1] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[2] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[2] + '</span></td>';}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is there an actual problem executing this code?

Comment: The initial if/else statement runs fine, but the nested if (Category 1 onwards) doesn't display the images that it should be pulling from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this waterfall logic. In your example you return immediately in your else statement. Category 1, 2, 3 if statements are never reached.

```
function generateMarkup(handValue) {
    if (handValue >= 0.9) {
        return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "You can play any two cards from this position.";
    }

    if (handValue < 0.06) {
        return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td>';   
    }

    if (handValue < 0.20) {
        return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[1] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[1] + '</span></td>';
    }

    if (handValue < 0.40) {
        return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = '<tr><td class="tooltip"><img src="' + startHand[0] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[0] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[1] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[1] + '</span></td><td class="tooltip">' + startHand[2] + '.jpg"><span class="tooltiptext">' + toolTips[2] + '</span></td>';
    }

    return document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = 'You should play if your cards are in one of the following categories:<br><br><table>';
}
```

Comment: So by using return in the else statement, once it executes the function ends?

Comment: That is correct! Using return in a function will immediately end the execution of said function and return the return value.

Comment: Thanks mate - that has definitely helped.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the first answer you can make the following improvements.

1) Use double quotes for string arrays its a better way according to w3schools

```
 var startHand = ["images/cards/cardResult1",
                     "images/cards/cardResult2"];
```

2) If you are not using the return values take them off

```
    function generateMarkup(handValue) {
        if (handValue >= 0.9) {
           document.getElementById("resultText").innerHTML = "You can play any two cards from this position.";

     }

//More lines of code
//...
//...

  }
```

3)Check out a library like JQuery that will make things easier

```
    function generateMarkup(handValue) {
            if (handValue >= 0.9) {
              $("#resultText").html("You can play any two cards from this position.");

        } 

    //More lines of code
    //...
    //...

   }
```

Comment: The return is absolutely paramount in the provided answer, it ends the logic tree execution. jQuery is a horrible library in my opinion. It's bloated and slow. Learning the fundamentals of javascript will help you tremendously if you're a developer. If you understand javascript at it's core, you will be able to learn any framework or library through api documentation. Learning jQuery will not help you understand something like react, angular, or nodejs.

Comment: @KyleRichardson about the return statement if thats the case then its necessary to put a single "return;" at the end of the function rather than repeating it numerous times, about jQuery you are correct my suggestion was not given as a learning option for a beginner but as an option to reduce the amount of code he has to write. Besides the flaws of the library is being worked on as time moves on as it is open source.

Comment: No, you can have multiple return statements.  The code I gave works perfectly without modification.  Read here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: I haven't said you code does not work! and I haven't said the return statements are unnecessary . My suggestion only applies  if the return values are not used. Its better to add a single "return;" at the end of the function if its only use is to ensure termination.

Comment: Look at the example I gave, the last line of the function is a return. I'm lost as to what you're saying.

Comment: Ok! all it's good. I failed to confirm that at least one return statement was out of an if block.